# como arreglo estas vulnerabilidades de node

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs

El problema es que siempre me salen estas vulnerabilidades, pero acabo de usar el npx create-react-app,no he instalado nada que las provoque,ya use el npm audit fix --force, así que no se que puede estar pasando, tengo la versión de node v16.0.0 y npm 7.10.0

aquí las vulnerabilidades:
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN audit Updating react-scripts to 2.1.8,which is a SemVer major change.
npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated kleur@2.0.2: Please upgrade to kleur@3 or migrate to 'ansi-colors' if you prefer the old syntax. Visit [https://github.com/lukeed/kleur/releases/tag/v3.0.0\](https://github.com/lukeed/kleur/releases/tag/v3.0.0%5C) for migration path(s).
npm WARN deprecated eslint-loader@2.1.1: This loader has been deprecated. Please use eslint-webpack-plugin
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated html-webpack-plugin@4.0.0-alpha.2: please switch to a stable version
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@9.0.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.4: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.

added 519 packages, removed 699 packages, changed 359 packages, and audited 1832 packages in 27s

58 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

## npm audit report

braces  <2.3.1
Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/786
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@4.0.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/braces
micromatch  0.2.0 - 2.3.11
Depends on vulnerable versions of braces
node_modules/micromatch
jest-cli  12.1.1-alpha.2935e14d || 12.1.2-alpha.6230044c - 24.8.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-config
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-haste-map
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-snapshot
Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
node_modules/jest-cli
jest  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.4 || 23.4.0 - 23.6.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-cli
node_modules/jest
react-scripts  >=0.3.0-alpha
Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-loader
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-safe-parser
Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
Depends on vulnerable versions of terser-webpack-plugin
Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
node_modules/react-scripts
jest-config  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 24.0.0-alpha.16
Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-jasmine2
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-util
Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
node_modules/jest-config
jest-runner  21.0.0-alpha.1 - 22.4.4 || 23.4.0 - 23.6.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-config
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-haste-map
node_modules/jest-runner
jest-runtime  12.1.1-alpha.2935e14d - 24.8.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-plugin-istanbul
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-config
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-haste-map
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-util
Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
node_modules/jest-runtime
jest-haste-map  16.1.0-alpha.691b0e22 - 24.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
Depends on vulnerable versions of sane
node_modules/jest-haste-map
jest-message-util  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 23.1.0 || 23.4.0 - 24.0.0-alpha.16
Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
node_modules/jest-message-util
expect  21.0.0-beta.1 - 22.4.3 || 23.4.0 - 23.6.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
node_modules/expect
jest-jasmine2  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.4 || 23.4.0 - 23.6.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of expect
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-snapshot
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-util
node_modules/jest-jasmine2
jest-snapshot  23.4.0 - 23.6.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
node_modules/jest-snapshot
jest-resolve-dependencies  23.4.0 - 23.6.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-snapshot
node_modules/jest-resolve-dependencies
jest-util  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.3 || 23.4.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
node_modules/jest-util
jest-environment-jsdom  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.3 || 23.4.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-util
node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom
jest-environment-node  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.3 || 23.4.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-util
node_modules/jest-environment-node
test-exclude  <=4.2.3
Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
node_modules/test-exclude
babel-plugin-istanbul  <=5.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of test-exclude
node_modules/babel-plugin-istanbul
babel-jest  14.2.0-alpha.ca8bfb6e - 24.0.0-alpha.16
Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-plugin-istanbul
node_modules/babel-jest

immer  <8.0.1
Severity: high
Prototype Pollution - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1603
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@4.0.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/immer
react-dev-utils  6.0.6-next.9b4009d7 - 11.0.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of immer
node_modules/react-dev-utils
react-scripts  >=0.3.0-alpha
Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-loader
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-safe-parser
Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
Depends on vulnerable versions of terser-webpack-plugin
Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
node_modules/react-scripts

merge  <2.1.1
Severity: high
Prototype Pollution - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1666
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@4.0.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/merge
exec-sh  <=0.3.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of merge
node_modules/exec-sh
sane  1.0.4 - 4.0.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of exec-sh
Depends on vulnerable versions of watch
node_modules/sane
jest-haste-map  16.1.0-alpha.691b0e22 - 24.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
Depends on vulnerable versions of sane
node_modules/jest-haste-map
jest-cli  12.1.1-alpha.2935e14d || 12.1.2-alpha.6230044c - 24.8.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-config
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-haste-map
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-snapshot
Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
node_modules/jest-cli
jest  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.4 || 23.4.0 - 23.6.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-cli
node_modules/jest
react-scripts  >=0.3.0-alpha
Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-loader
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-safe-parser
Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
Depends on vulnerable versions of terser-webpack-plugin
Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
node_modules/react-scripts
jest-runner  21.0.0-alpha.1 - 22.4.4 || 23.4.0 - 23.6.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-config
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-haste-map
node_modules/jest-runner
jest-runtime  12.1.1-alpha.2935e14d - 24.8.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-plugin-istanbul
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-config
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-haste-map
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-util
Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
node_modules/jest-runtime
watch  >=0.14.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of exec-sh
node_modules/watch

postcss  7.0.0 - 8.2.9
Severity: moderate
Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1693
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@4.0.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/postcss
autoprefixer  9.0.0 - 9.8.6
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/autoprefixer
css-blank-pseudo  *
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/css-blank-pseudo
postcss-preset-env  >=6.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of css-blank-pseudo
Depends on vulnerable versions of css-prefers-color-scheme
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-color-gray
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-double-position-gradients
node_modules/postcss-preset-env
css-has-pseudo  *
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/css-has-pseudo
css-prefers-color-scheme  *
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/css-prefers-color-scheme
postcss-attribute-case-insensitive  4.0.0 - 4.0.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-attribute-case-insensitive
postcss-color-functional-notation  >=2.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-color-functional-notation
postcss-color-gray  >=5.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-color-gray
postcss-color-hex-alpha  4.0.0 - 6.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-color-hex-alpha
postcss-color-mod-function  >=3.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-color-mod-function
postcss-color-rebeccapurple  >=4.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-color-rebeccapurple
postcss-custom-media  7.0.0 - 7.0.8
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-custom-media
postcss-custom-properties  8.0.0 - 10.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-custom-properties
postcss-custom-selectors  5.0.0 - 5.1.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-custom-selectors
postcss-dir-pseudo-class  >=5.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-dir-pseudo-class
postcss-double-position-gradients  *
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-double-position-gradients
postcss-env-function  >=2.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-env-function
postcss-flexbugs-fixes  4.0.0 - 4.2.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-flexbugs-fixes
postcss-focus-visible  >=4.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-focus-visible
postcss-focus-within  >=3.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-focus-within
postcss-font-variant  4.0.0 - 4.0.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-font-variant
postcss-gap-properties  >=2.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-gap-properties
postcss-image-set-function  >=3.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-image-set-function
postcss-initial  3.0.0 - 3.0.4
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-initial
postcss-lab-function  >=2.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-lab-function
postcss-loader  3.0.0 - 4.0.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-loader
react-scripts  >=0.3.0-alpha
Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-loader
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-safe-parser
Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
Depends on vulnerable versions of terser-webpack-plugin
Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
node_modules/react-scripts
postcss-logical  >=2.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-logical
postcss-media-minmax  4.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-media-minmax
postcss-nesting  7.0.0 - 7.0.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-nesting
postcss-overflow-shorthand  >=2.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-overflow-shorthand
postcss-page-break  2.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-page-break
postcss-place  >=4.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-place
postcss-pseudo-class-any-link  >=6.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-pseudo-class-any-link
postcss-replace-overflow-wrap  3.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-replace-overflow-wrap
postcss-safe-parser  4.0.0 - 4.0.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-safe-parser
postcss-selector-matches  >=4.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-selector-matches
postcss-selector-not  4.0.0 - 4.0.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-selector-not

serialize-javascript  <=3.0.0
Severity: high
Cross-Site Scripting - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1426
Remote Code Execution - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1548
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@4.0.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/serialize-javascript
terser-webpack-plugin  <=1.4.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of serialize-javascript
node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin
react-scripts  >=0.3.0-alpha
Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-loader
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-safe-parser
Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
Depends on vulnerable versions of terser-webpack-plugin
Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
node_modules/react-scripts

yargs-parser  <=13.1.1 || 14.0.0 - 15.0.0 || 16.0.0 - 18.1.1
Prototype Pollution - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1500
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@4.0.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/yargs-parser
node_modules/yargs-parser
yargs  4.0.0-alpha1 - 12.0.5 || 14.1.0 || 15.0.0 - 15.2.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs-parser
node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/yargs
node_modules/yargs
jest-cli  12.1.1-alpha.2935e14d || 12.1.2-alpha.6230044c - 24.8.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-config
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-haste-map
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-snapshot
Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
node_modules/jest-cli
jest  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.4 || 23.4.0 - 23.6.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-cli
node_modules/jest
react-scripts  >=0.3.0-alpha
Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-loader
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-safe-parser
Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
Depends on vulnerable versions of terser-webpack-plugin
Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
node_modules/react-scripts
jest-runtime  12.1.1-alpha.2935e14d - 24.8.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-plugin-istanbul
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-config
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-haste-map
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-util
Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
node_modules/jest-runtime
webpack-dev-server  2.0.0-beta - 3.10.3
Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
node_modules/webpack-dev-server

69 vulnerabilities (21 low, 39 moderate, 9 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force